# git push doesn't add anything to remote repo despite changes

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have:

```
jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ git add .
[jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ git add -A
 
[jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ 
[jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ 
[jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ git commit -m "test"
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
 
[jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com': monajalal
Password for 'https://monajalal@github.com': 
Everything up-to-date
```

and

```
[jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate
* 9ef6d1d (HEAD, master) pushing to private repo
* 299b426 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Updated code to reflect release version of data format (#6)
* 13fdaf1 Latest version
* 2a18c5d Initial commit
* add1765 Update README.md
* 8aabaf3 Initial commit
```

and

```
[jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ git config --get remote.origin.url
https://github.com/monajalal/fashion_compatibility.git
```

Where

```
https://github.com/monajalal/fashion_compatibility.git
```

Is a private git repo of me and only has a README as seen below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your local repo is based off of the [mvasil/fashion_compatibility](https://github.com/mvasil/fashion-compatibility) repo, which has 5 commits on `master` with the most recent commit being `299b426` which matches `origin/master` in your local repo.

At some point, it appears you set your remote origin to your own repo, monajalal/fashion_compatibility, however it appears to be an entirely different repo. Your repo looks like it is freshly initialized with only one branch called `main`, with a single commit beginning with `ffa...` which isn't in any of your commits. Somehow you still have an origin setup from the old repo. (By chance did you change your remote from the config instead of by adding it? The fix for this is below.)

I believe this repo discrepancy is causing the problem. If your goal is to replace your GitHub repo with what you have locally, I would try to remove your remote:

```
git remote remove origin
```

Then re-add it:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/monajalal/fashion_compatibility.git
# Now push out your branch and set it's upstream
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Now your repo will have 2 branches: `main` and `master`. In GitHub, change the default branch of your repo to point to the `master` branch instead of `main`, and then delete the `main` branch. Now from your command prompt you can `git fetch`, which should do nothing, but confirm you're all synced up.

Comment: I want to push it to my own repo at monajalal right

Comment: @MonaJalal - yes. I believe the steps I laid out will do that. I'm assuming you don't mind deleting the one commit you have there on branch `main`.

Comment: TTT worked but how do I merge master and main? it is showing as a pull request https://imgur.com/a/Nk9jw6v

Comment: @MonaJalal I can't see that image for some reason, but, my understanding is that you don't need the `main` branch, so you should be able to simply delete it both locally and remote. (I'm assuming you don't have any new local commits on `main` that you care about.) This assumption is based on the fact that the repo you started from only had `master`, and `main` was just the default branch when you created the GitHub repo and only has one commit with the template readme file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your status again. I can reproduce your symptoms by resetting my tracking branch to its parent:

```
$ demo() { 
        ( set -x
          git clone -ns . `mktemp -d`; cd $_
          git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master{,~}
          git status
          git push
          git status
        )
}
$ demo
++ mktemp -d
+ git clone -ns . /tmp/jthill/tmp.zHlRYe2LiO
Cloning into '/tmp/jthill/tmp.zHlRYe2LiO'...
done.
+ cd /tmp/jthill/tmp.zHlRYe2LiO
+ git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master refs/remotes/origin/master~
+ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        [… ersatz deletions from no-checkout scratch clone … ]    
+ git push
Everything up-to-date
+ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        [… ersatz deletions from no-checkout scratch clone … ]    


$ git clone -ns . `mktemp -d`; cd $_
Cloning into '/tmp/jthill/tmp.ySqFsGa9MI'...
done.
$ git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master{,~}
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
[… ersatz deletions from the no-checkout scratch clone …]
$
```

and since `git push` checks with the remote it updates the tracking refs for you kinda on the q.t,

Comment: could you please have a look at my log and see what I am probably doing wrong? https://pastebin.com/raw/BNs8DjnZ

Comment: What I'm saying is, you did `git status` based on outdated tracking information about the remote refs. When you pushed,  you updated the remote refs and your local tracking refs, syncing them.

Comment: how do I merge master and main? it is showing as a pull request imgur.com/a/Nk9jw6v